# Верующий, неверующий

Tags: грамматика, части-речи

К какой из частей речи относятся слова верующий и неверующий (к причастию или к имени существительному)?

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2):

В зависимости от контекста это:

- причастие: *Он, верующий ей во всём, сделал немало глупых ошибок* (такое употребление выглядит архаично, конечно же);
- отглагольное прилагательное: *Василий — человек истово верующий, с ним лучше не говорить о религии*;
- существительное (субстантивированное причастие): *На улицах города собрались тысячи верующих и поклоняются идолам*.